# How to split the string on a dot in such a way such that each user has set of attributes?

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary, set

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here. I have a List of string `(userIdList)` which looks like below -

```
[event.1386979194020.24551521.DC1, modela.1386979194020.24551521.DC1]
```

Above format is like below -

```
A.B.C.D
```

Here, C is the `user-id` and A is the `attribute name`. So in the above example, for the first string in the above list - `24551521` is the `user-id` and `event` is the attribute name. Similarly for the second string in the above list, `modela` is the attribute name and `24551521` is the user-id.

As you can see that, `24551521` user-id has two attributes which are `event` and `modela`.

So I am trying to iterate the `userIdList` and make a map such that, key in the map has `24551521` as the user-id and value in the map will be a set of string and it should be `event` and `modela`,

But somehow, in my below code, I always see - `24551521` as the key of map and `modela` in the set of string value not both `event` and `modela` in the set.

Below is my Java code in which I am trying to iterate `userIdList`-

```
Map<String, Set<String>> userAttribute = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();

for(String ss : userIdList) {
    Set<String> attributeTypes = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    attributeTypes.add(ss.split("\\.")[0]);         

    // this always override my previous set value
    userAttribute.put(ss.split("\\.")[2], attributeTypes);
}
```

If I print out `userAttribute` map, I always see `24551521` as the key and `modela` as the set value which is not what I want. But it should be `24551521` and set of strings - `event` and `modela`

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Your code seems to be working properly since everytime you add a new element to the Set attributeTypes, the set gets updated. So the Map userAttribute is also updated with the new Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration you are defining new Set and then writing it to Map (overwriting old one).
You should check if there is Set for this id and update it

```
    Set<String> attributeTypes;
    String id = ss.split("\\.")[2];
    if(userAttribute.containsKey(id))
        attributeTypes = userAttribute.get(id);
    else
        attributeTypes = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    attributeTypes.add(ss.split("\\.")[0]);

    userAttribute.put(id, attributeTypes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only create the Set for the key *once*, by checking if it's there first and if it's not, create a new one and put it in the map:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> userAttribute = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();

for (String ss : userIdList) {
    String id = ss.split("\\.")[2];
    Set<String> attributeTypes = userAttribute.get(id);
    if (attributeTypes == null) { // null is returned if there's no entry
        attributeTypes = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        userAttribute.put(id, attributeTypes);
    }
    attributeTypes.add(ss.split("\\.")[0]);         
}
```

Notice how there's only a call to `map.put()` (if it's a new `id` encountered). Also, there's only one call to `map.get()` and no calls to `map.contains()` - this is the most efficient way to do it.